# How to insert into an struct array (athena)?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

i have this field in my dataset

```
events
array<struct<status:string,context:map<string,string>,measurements:array<struct<context:map<string,string>,values:map<string,double>,type:string,subType:string,id:string,deviceId:string,timestamp:bigint>>,type:string,subType:string,id:string,deviceId:string,timestamp:bigint>>
```

i have to insert an empty field into this, because empty fields are in illegal from a parquet.

How can i do it ?